# How to localize static text via storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, storyboard

Currently I have a project I'm localizing for various markets. The current localization currently works but I'm doing it in code and it's adding a lot more heft to the project. ie.

```
NSLocalizedString("Welcome", comment: "")
```

Is there a way to do all the static localization within storyboard itself to cut down on all the superfluous code in the viewcontrollers?

Comment: Where is this context menu you speak of?

Comment: Are you talking about the top bar menu "Editor" -> "Localization Locking"?

Comment: Sorry, it has changed since I last looked at localisation; you add the language to your project and then you can manage the localisation of the storyboard by selecting the base storyboard and then you can add a localisation strings file for your storyboard. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW3